# Load multiple products by custom attribute into a collection [magento]

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Doing this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('ordernumber', 500);
```

gives me an object of a product, which means everything with the custom attribute (`ordernumber`) is fine.

Doing this, though:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('ordernumber')
->addAttributeToFilter('ordernumber', 500);
```

returns a collection, but an empty one - without items. And they should be 3. Couple of hours ago it worked. Now it stopped working, and I haven't changed anything concerning the collection or the attribute. I have no clue what the problem might be...

The attribute is set to `Yes` for the `Usied in Product Listing`

Comment: How did you add the custom attribute `ordernumber`? Programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
$products =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('ordernumber', '500');
```

ANOTHER WAY

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('ordernumber','500')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code may not work if you are using it on frontend and the flat catalog is enabled.
To make it work, you have 2 possibilities:
*Option 1:*
Make the attribute `ordernumber` to be used in product listing. Edit the attribute in the backend and set the flag `Used in product listing` to `Yes`. Reindex is required.
*Option 2:*
Use the eav collection directly:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('ordernumber')
->addAttributeToFilter('ordernumber', 500);
```

I recommend the first approach.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I updated my answer - It is set to YES for the Product Listing.

Comment: @Milkncookiez. Make sure you rebuilt the Flat product index.

Comment: @Milkncookiez Even if the indexes are "green" they may not be up to date. Check if there is a column named `ordernumber` in any table that starts with `catalog_product_flat_`. If there isn't then rebuild your indexes.

Comment: I rebuilt the indexes. Now even loading a single the product by the custom attribute doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Please Make Sure `Used in Product Listing` option set to `yes` for Attributes `ordernumber`.

After that clear cache. Hope this will work.

Comment: It is set to YES from the beginning.